# I'm looking for an idiom to describe improvement

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example, something like, "take to the next level."

Some possibilities I've already found are: *improve*, *enhance*, *upgrade* and, of course, *take to the next level*. These don't do the job for me for several reasons: they aren't powerful enough; they're overused; and some, especially "take to the next level," are simply cringe-worthy.

Context: I need to convey the idea that a web-based recruitment platform (conceived, created and marketed by the company I work for) will improve the recruitment process of our clients. E.g.

> Our platform will take your recruitment process [—to the next level—].

(I know, gimmicky!) The criteria upon which I will base my judgement include originality and how captivating the phrase/idiom is.

Comment: Your own "take to the next level" works.

Comment: Please review the tag-info for the *-request tags: we need to know the context, what you have already found and why those results were not suitable; what criteria you will use to judge the best answer. Questions can always be brought off-hold once they are edited to be complete.

Comment: @Lawrence though I swear I'm going to scream if I hear it used one more time. That phrase is seriously overworked and I applaud Alessandro for looking for an alternative.

Comment: @Spagirl Whoa, that's really taking it to the next level. :P

Comment: @Spagirl But on a more serious note, doesn't *idiom* status imply wide usage anyway, *regardless of the phrasing*? The OP might be better off using his own words that suit his specific context.

Comment: @Lawrence It probably does. My issue with taking things to the next level is entirely a personal objection to its ubiquity. On looking it up I see it has been used by Nike advertising, which I wasn't aware of and which probably explains its popularity. ODO defines it more narrowly than 'improve', giving it as *improve/develop something that is already successful*. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take_something_to_the_next_level

Comment: @Spagirl +1 That's a useful tidbit. (Also, I humbly apologise for yanking your chain and thank you for not screaming.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hi Andrew, I added come context to the question, so please consider putting it live again. Thank you

Comment: @Spagirl Completely agree with you, so overused and honestly quite cringe-worthy, hence why I was seeking out alternatives.

Comment: Requests like this need to be complete (there are those who would ban them completely). As well the context (thank you), we need to know what you have already found (*improve, enhance, upgrade,* and their synonyms) and why those results were not suitable; and what criteria you will use to judge the best answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for your patience. I revised the question once again in the attempt of covering the abovementioned issues. Thank you

Comment: Or you could fully embrace the cheesy cringe-worthiness and take it to the next level with “Our platform will take/step your recruitment process up to the “hire” level/notch where it belongs."

Comment: Hats off to you @PapaPoule. Love the pun; I would seriously consider using it if only our platform wasn't targeted at stand-offish, humourless wolf-of-wall-street-like financial executives.

Comment: Consider [up the ante](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20the%20ante) **-to set a higher standard or
 goal**, or if you don't mind to rephrasing your sentence; try [raise the bar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raise) ** -to set a higher standard**

Answer (score 2):

***[A leap forward](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-giant-step-leap-stride)***:

> important progress

- Your recruitment process will make a big/giant leap forward with our platform.

MacMillan Dictionary

Comment: "A leap forward"...off the edge of the cliff, does it for me!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to "Our platform will bring your recruitment process to a new stage" is:

> Our platform will take your recruitment process **a step further**.

**one step ahead** is another possibility.

> Definition: to be slightly better prepared or more successful than
>   someone else.
>
> Example: *Throughout the incident, the hijackers were always one step
>   ahead of the police*.

[[*The Free Dictionary*]](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+step+ahead)

Answer (score 1):

**Kick it up a notch**

> To make something more exciting, intense, or interesting, as a food dish or a social gathering ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kick-it-up-a-notch))

This is a catch phrase used by chef Emeril Lagasse, and it may be trademarked.

**Up to eleven**

This is a [pop culture idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven) referring to a guitar amplifier that has a volume know that goes a step beyond any other in existence. (Ten was the limit on all the others).

Not very original for an ad campaign, but you might get away with it.

**into orbit**

> Informal, Into a state of heightened activity ([English Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/into_orbit))

**Supercharge**

> to charge with an abundant or excessive amount, as of energy, emotion, or tension ([Dictionary.com verb #1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supercharged))

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, I love "supercharged"

Answer (score 1):

***[Scale new/great/dizzy heights](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scale-new-dizzy-great-heights)*****:**

> to achieve a high level of success in a particular activity

- The team scaled new heights with their Cup Final victory.

MacMillan Dictionary

***[scale the heights](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scale-the-heights)*****:**

> If you scale the heights of a type of work, you are very successful in it

- At the age of 35, she had already scaled the heights of the acting profession.

Cambridge Dictionary. 

You could rewrite your sentence as follows: 
Our platform will let your recruitment process scale new heights.

Or.

With our platform, your recruitment process will scale new heights.

***[Soar](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soar)*****:**

> to rise very quickly to a high level.

- Temperatures will soar over the weekend, say the weather forecasters.

Cambridge Online Dictionary.

Our platform will make your recruitment process soar (achieve great heights).

Or.

Our platform will make your recruitment process soar above the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If your potential clients’ current recruitment systems are truly borderline archaic (and if you think they can handle having this being pointed out to them in a somewhat aggressive manner), I don't think it's too late in the century for you to consider using the notion of:

> [drag{ing} someone/something into the 21st century/the modern
>   world](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/drag-someone-something-into-the-21st-century-the-modern-world)
>   definition and synonyms
>    PHRASE
>     to make a person or organization do things in a more modern way
>     Synonyms and related
>   words
>   To make something more modern or fashionable:
>     update,
>   modernize, drag someone/something into /the 21st century/the modern
>   world...

(from *MacMillan Dictionary*)

Please note, however, that if this is something that you would consider, I would **strongly recommend** softening it by replacing “drag” with “bring” in your case, and perhaps you could add the bracketed language:

> Our platform will **bring** your recruitment process [roaring] **into the
>   21st Century** [and help prepare it for the next one].

See the first line of [this *Innovation Warehouse* article](http://www.innovationwarehouse.org/blog/startup-stories-launchpad-recruits-uses-video-interviews-to-find-hidden-gems-faster/) for an example of the expression (with bring) being used in the recruitment field.

---

If the above suggestion is deemed unacceptable for any of the concerns raised in my answer or the comments to it, perhaps you could play on the notion of progressing [“From a Process to a System”](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ495215) (as that notion is discussed [granted, presumably, based on my reading of  the linked *ERIC* “abstract”]  in an article with that title, by Roger Chevalier) and use it with a term that seemingly has a specific positive meaning in your field:

> ”Our platform will transform your current recruitment activities from a mere process to a[n
>   efficient] [recruitment management
>   system](http://searchfinancialapplications.techtarget.com/definition/recruitment-management-system).
>
> **recruitment management system**
>
> A recruitment management system (RMS), also known as an e-recruitment
>   or online recruitment system, is a multi-component software tool
>   designed to automate and facilitate the processes involved in finding,
>   attracting, assessing, interviewing and hiring new personnel.

(from *techtarget.com*)

Comment: You never cease to impress me! I'll have to discuss with my manager, but thanks so much for the suggestion.

Comment: How can a platform help a client enter the 21st if they're already in it? It's 2017 afterall

Comment: I'd say the 2020s or the *third millennium*

Comment: @Mari-LouA My suggestion didn't mean to imply that "the client" was not already in the 21st century but that the client's "recruitment process" was not & therefore needed to be improved/modernized (note that the notion of "help" isn't in the first clause). Likewise, the "it" in the last bracketed suggestion also refers to the "recruitment process" (& not the "client") as the thing that will be helped going forward to the next (22nd) century. Maybe it's just here in the US, but entities, even human ones in very high places, can "be" in the current century & yet use outdated [thought] processes.

Comment: Show me a programme today that uses the same  technology from the 1990s. The idiom "dragging someone into the 21st century" is, ironically,  out-dated, old-fashioned, and in 2017 an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0):

> Our platform will take your recruitment process ***several notches
>   higher***.

ODO:

> **[notch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notch)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> 1.3 A point or degree in a scale.
>
> ‘Petrov's burgeoning running power and growing sangfroid when
>   presented with openings which his fizzing forwards have engineered
>   have allowed him to ratchet up his game **several notches** over the past
>   six months.’

Foboko sentence dictionary:

> [Notches in a sentence:](https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/notches)
>   Ge Zhonghai martial skills were really
>   several notches higher than Mei.

Comment: Your second example suggests yet another phrase that I have heard used in approximately the sense that the poster asks about: "step up [one's] game." The original context was presumably sports, but the phrase has long since passed into business and popular usage.